# Java Regex - What does each of these parts do?

Tags: java, regex, expression

```
if(password.matches("(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(\\w{8,})") )
        System.out.println("Valid Password");
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid Password");
```

I am checking a password to ensure it has at least 8 characters in length, which can be letters or digits and it must have at least 2 digits.  This appears to work for me but I just wanted to confirm I was doing this right. Also, I have been trying to research and figure out exactly what each piece is doing.  Below is what I believe each piece to be doing, but if I am incorrect, would you please explain what the particular portion is actually doing.  Thanks

?= tells the program to remember if the digits [0-9] which I am looking for are found ?

.* says for any number of [0-9]?

[0-9] Specifies any number from 0-9.

.*[0-9] Then the regex looks for another number from 0-9 ?

(\\w{8,}) looks for any letters (uppercase or lowercase) and digits, with a minimum length of 8 characters?

Comment: Look at the explanation panel: http://regex101.com/r/dG8zD1/1

Comment: That website is awesome!  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That regex has two main parts:

1. `(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])`
2. `(\\w{8,})`

Part 1. is a *positive look ahead*, which has the form `(?=pattern)`. "Look arounds" (positive/negative look behinds/aheads) assert, without consuming (or capturing), that the adjacent input matches a certain pattern. In this case, it's asserting that the input following the current point contains (at least) 2 digits (`.*` meaning 0-n chars, `[0-9]` meaning any number character). Incidentally, it could be expressed more succinctly as `(?=(.*[0-9]){2}`

Part 2. means "at least 8 word characters" - a word character is any letter, any number or an underscore. The brackets around it (unnecessarily) capture the 8+ word characters as group 1

Answer (score 0):

```
?= is a positive look ahead, That means that it is searching for something ahead of it.
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

For more info on the look ahead.

http://rubular.com/

Great for testing out any regex.